# SOLR 4 - how to index html plain text

Tags: solr

With SOLR 4, how can I index a plain text document with HTML code inside of it, without the HTML being stripped out?

example, `<b>bold text</b>` is turned into `bold text`

Thanks!

Comment: Guruji please share your db schema.xml. I am tired searching how to strip/ignore html tags from being indexed in solr.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the fieldType for the field where you are storing your text document is implementing the `solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory`. This is removing the `<b> </b>` tags from your document when it is being stored in the index. You can check this in your schema.xml file.

You will need to modify the fieldType for this field by either removing that [CharFilterFactory](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/CharFilterFactories) or defining a new field type that has that removed. For additional information about setting up your schema please refer to following resources.

- [Documents, Fields and Schema Design](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Documents,+Fields,+and+Schema+Design)
- [Understanding Analyzers, Tokenizers & Filters](http://docs.lucidworks.com/display/solr/Understanding+Analyzers,+Tokenizers,+and+Filters)

Comment: Sorry, I already tried this yesterday. Thanks for the help though! I think the problem is with Tika.

Comment: Yes, Solr Cell with Tika does not retain the original formatting of the document. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770605/can-solr-retain-the-formatting-of-the-html-documents-whcih-was-fed-to-it-in-it